# How to use ILP data types with QuestDB data types?

Tags: questdb

I use QuestDb with Influx Line Protocol. When I send new metric QuestDB automatically creates a table and for all my numbers it uses DOUBLE type. Also it can create SYMBOL for Tags and String for other string fields in the message and LONG for numbers ending with 'i'.

So I can send

```
sensors,location=ny temperature=22,flag=6i,name="out" 1465839830100400200
```

and it will create

```
location SYMBOL
temperature DOUBLE
flag LONG
name STRING
```

How can I control what type is created if I want to have FLOAT instead of DOUBLE or INT, SHORT or BYTE instead of LONG?

Answer (score 0):

Influx Line Protocol does not have necessary granularity of types to cover all QuestDB types. The way to use of different data types is to pre-create the in QuestDB table before sending ILP metrics data. So if you create a table like this

```
create table abc (
  location SYMBOL,
  temperature FLOAT,
  flag BYTE,
  name STRING,
  date DATE,
  ts TIMESTAMPE
) timestamp(ts) partition by MONTH
```

you can then send this ILP data

```
sensors,location=ny temperature=22,flag=6i,name="out",date=1465839830100400 1465839830100400200000
```

Here `date` is epoch millisecond and after the space `ts` is in nano microseconds.

Last nano second timestamp can be omitted and then server will add timestamp on every message at the moment it appends it to the table.